# Dynamically resize input

Tags: jquery, input

I was just wondering how do you dynamically resize an input as you type in it??

I'd like to use jQuery if possible & I would rather it be a small script than a bulky plugin.

Please let me know,
Matt Mueller

Answer (score 7):

Here's a quick (untested) solution

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
  $(this).attr({width: 'auto', size: $(this).val().length});
});
```

Comment: I'll give this a go and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I just tried this and it works. But make sure you're not overriding the size with CSS, or it won't work.

Comment: Note that this adds too much space if you're using a variable-width font. Try typing 'iiiiiiiii' into the field to test it.

Answer (score 5):

I have a jQuery plugin on GitHub: https://github.com/MartinF/jQuery.Autosize.Input

It is about 1.6 kb minified.

You can see an live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mJMpw/6/

Example:

```
<input type="text" value="" placeholder="Autosize" data-autosize-input='{ "space": 40 }' />

input[type="data-autosize-input"] {
  width: 90px;
  min-width: 90px;
  max-width: 300px;
  transition: width 0.25s;    
}
```

You just use css to set min/max-width and use a transition on the width if you want a nice effect.

You can specify the space / distance to the end as the value in json notation for the data-autosize-input attribute on the input element.

Of course you can also just initialize it using jQuery

```
$("selector").autosizeInput();
```

Answer (score -1):

I found this lightweight one. This is for textareas

[jQuery plugin: ‘autoResize’](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/)

Full version : ~4k

Minified     : ~1k

Comment: I need it for inputs not for textareas. I checked that one out also. It looks like it bases its resize off of how many times you hit return.. that won't work. I want it to resize right when it reaches the end of the input box.