# HTML text input size

Tags: javascript, html, textinput

I have a text input created dynamically with javascript where I am putting some text with javascript also.
I would like to make the text input size variable, dependent on the text length and with maximum width of 70%

For that, I am using:

```
'<input type="text" style="max-width:70%" name="affiliation"
 id="affiliation'+affiliation_id+'" value="'+article_affiliations[i].name+'"
 size='+article_affiliations[i].name.length+'/>'
```

Everything works fine when the text is longer than 68% but when not, the text input area is smaller than the text size.

For example, when the text size is 118, the textarea wil be only 106 characters length and I don't know why. Any help and suggestion will be highly appreciable.

Thank you.

Comment: What is "size?" Length in characters? Height in pixels? Width in pixels? And why are there so many `;` between the attributes of the `input` element?

Comment: @AaronDigulla The size attribut in html is the length in characters.

Comment: @Milos: See my answer given below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Javascript:**

```
function incSize(event) {
   var size = event.value.length; 
   event.setAttribute("size", size);
   event.setAttribute("style", "width:auto")    
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="affiliation" onkeyup="incSize(this)" size="1" />​
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/vgZHh/)

Comment: Thank you A.K. In fact, I don't need to cach the keyup because I am populating the text input also with javascript.

Comment: As you type really long numbers, the first digit starts to go off to the left, not an ideal solution.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the style attribute then try this:

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(){
  $(this).attr({width: 'auto', size: $(this).val().length});
});
```

Make sure no CSS styles are overriding the width.
Got the answer from here: [Dynamically resize input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475358/dynamically-resize-input)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I would like to use only javascript and HTML, no JQuerry.

Comment: @Milos: See my answer with a javascript solution.